# In Foreach File write not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a code like this. In PHP i want create the json file through foreach loop. My array like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [out] => Array ( [id] => 5 [title] => Network [url] => network [label] => forum [tag] => 218 ) [filename] => tags/tag_218 ) [1] => Array ( [out] => Array ( [id] => 6 [title] => Arch [url] => arch [label] => forum [tag] => 218 ) [filename] => tags/tag_218 ) [2] => Array ( [out] => Array ( [id] => 7 [title] => not [url] => not [label] => forum [tag] => 218 )
```

In my code:

```
foreach($my_arr as $arr){
    $file_name=$arr['filename']; 
    $response=$arr['out'];
    if(!(file_exists($file_name))){
        $fp = fopen($file_name.'.json', 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, '$response');
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else{
        $fpd = fopen($file_name.'.json', 'a+');
        fwrite($fpd, '$response');
        fclose($fpd);
    }
}
```

Here text file was created. But only the last data got append. Why?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Here text file created. but the last data only  inserted. why?

Comment: Where do you build your json?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fput instead of Fwrite like this:

```
foreach($my_arr as $arr){
$file_name=$arr['filename']; 
$response=$arr['out'];
if(!(file_exists($file_name))){
    $fp = fopen($file_name.'.json', 'w+');
    fput($fp, '$response');
    fclose($fp);
}
else{
    $fpd = fopen($file_name.'.json', 'a+');
    fput($fpd, '$response');
    fclose($fpd);
}
}
```

Sometimes, fwrite can be a bit of trouble when writing arrays to a file (oh the beauty of php)